# Ignore existing items and insert remaining items into databases using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, dao

I have textarea where i can enter site names to block. All the entered sites stores into SITES table.If any of the sites entered are there in SITES table we should ignore those sites and and insert remaining sites.

How should we do that using hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute a first query:

```
select site.name from Site site where site.name in (:enteredSiteNames)
```

Then remove all the found sites from the list of entered sites (since they're already in the database).

Then iterate over the remaining sites, and persist them.

Comment: Thanks for reply..I was using this query currently but i was looking for alternative solution. sorry for not mentioning this in my question..                                                        Does hibernate provide any solution for handling such scenarios?

Comment: It doesn't provide anything else than the above.

Answer (score 0):

All you can (and probably should) do in Hibernate or on the database level is to add a unique constraint to the field containing the site name. This will make sure that an exception is raised in case a duplicate would be added. But to prevent this exception, you will have to check for pre-existing sites in your application code, e.g. by using a query for each site to be added or by loading the complete table at once and then checking each entered site name.

Note that you will probably need some kind of normalization of the site name like trimming whitespace or converting to lower case to make sure you identify any duplicates (e.g. `www.EXAMPLE.com` and `www.example.com` should probably be considered equal). In Hibernate Validator, you can use a pattern constraint to enforce this normalization.